# How to use two wireless routers to set up one big network in large house

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

So we have moved into a much larger house than before and our current wireless router (A Netgear modem/router combo circa 2015) just isn't cutting it, as we get basically no signal at all upstairs. Luckily, the house is actually wired with cat 5 ports everywhere, so we do have the ability to plug the modem/router into the feed line and then use ethernet cables all over the house.

However, it would be nice to have wifi upstairs available, especially when guests are in town. I do happen to have access to an Apple Airport Extreme router as well, and obviously I can plug that into the cat 5 line upstairs and set up a new network.

However, I am wondering if it is at all possible for us to actually set it up as a way to access the same wifi network that is being originally created downstairs? I know it is possible to set it up as a repeater, but since we don't pay for particularly fast internet I would like to avoid any speed degradation by having it create the wireless signal from the wired cat 5 signal.

I apologize if I'm not using the right terminology. I'm actually a software developer so I'm confident that if someone can point me to some instructions I can follow them I just don't have any IT networking experience so I only half know what I'm talking about.

Thanks so much in advance!